# Is there a way to find if there is text on a website?

Tags: vb.net, web

So say that I want to find the word "Hello, world!" on a webpage. It has the ID "Text". Using a WebBrowser named WebBrowser1, is there a way return true if that text exists on a webpage, or if it doesn't exist, it will return false? The URL would be EXACTLY the same either way.

Edit: The HTML path to get to it is very long, so I'd need to find the text on the page.

Comment: not enough info. Remember we cant see your code, or have any idea whether you've even started writing it. Have you managed to hit a webpage with VB.NEt and retrieve the response as a string / block of text?  If yes, then you can use either a DOM parser, a reg expression or maybe even a set of simple strpos and substr to establish whether the text exists or not.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Anyway, it's a website like Stackoverflow, it's not just plain text, it has a ton of text and HTML on every page. I have been able to navigate to the website and check if it's loaded, but not check for the needed lines.

Comment: Ok, but when I say plain text, I just meant the HTTP response. Naturally this plain text does contain HTML markup, but in your app you would usually treat it as plain text until it goes into a DOM parser or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

```
Dim wb as new WebClient
Dim html as string = wb.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Then, you search that string, for that you can use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx#Y575).

Comment: Or if you want something more sophisticated you can search that string  using Regex ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.80).aspx )

Answer (score 1):

I second Luxspes's answer.

More code just to be more helpful.
Have not tested this yet I hope this works:

```
Dim wb As New WebClient
Dim html As String = wb.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com")
'To know if there are YOUR STRING inside
Dim BooleanAnswer As Boolean = html.Contains("YOUR STRING")
'To know how many instances
Dim HowMany As Integer = FindIndexes("YOUR STRING", html).Count
'To output them all through Console.Write or your preferred output(the indexes)
Dim FoundList As List(Of Integer) = FindIndexes("YOUR STRING", html)
For i As Integer = 0 to FoundList.Count - 1
            Console.Write(i & "-index: " & FoundList(i).toString)
Next i

'Function
Private Function FindIndexes(ByVal searchWord As String, ByVal src As String) as List(Of Integer)
            Dim searchSRC As String = src
            Dim toFind As String = searchWord
            Dim lastIndex As Integer = 0
            Dim listOfIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
            Do Until lastIndex < 0
                lastIndex = searchSRC.IndexOf(toFind, lastIndex + toFind.Length)
                If lastIndex >= 0 Then
                    listOfIndexes.Add(lastIndex)
                End If
            Loop
            Return listOfIndexes
End Function
```